# Implement JPA from own library

Tags: java, database, jpa

We have own ORM library in work project (DbConnector). And we want to remove it. But first of all we must to separate interfaces and implementations.
I want implement JPA through DbConnector. What steps should I do for write JPA implementation?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with that? Are you planning to offer your ORM framework to external parties and want it to be JPA compatible?

Comment: @Kayaman we just have project with 3 millions strings, and 20 modules. All modules depend on DbConnector, and i must break this dependency.

Comment: That's not something you solve by making your ORM implement JPA. Sounds like you don't have a properly layered architecture.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, its true. I fixed my question. First of all i must to separate interfaces and implementations. And first step its implement JPA in our DbConnector. And the second step it is changed implementation on other ORM. (for example Hibernate)

Comment: No, the first step is to create an abstraction layer (service layer) that's used by your system, instead of directly accessing your DbConnector. The second step is modifying that abstraction layer to use something more trustworthy than your own ORM framework. There is no "implement JPA" step anywhere, unless you're completely insane.

Comment: @Kayaman thank you for your comment

Comment: I hope you understand it and heed my suggestion. Your problem is (apparently) that your system is too tightly coupled to DbConnector. You want to solve it by coupling your system tightly to JPA. It won't do you much good.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, i understand you. We want to do new service and dao layer, but i dont know, how i can break dependencies in all modules after that? For example i separate all modules on 3 components (services,dao,repository/model) and after that i will write dao impl with DbConnector. How i can break depend with DbConnector?

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear to you. If you have a properly layered architecture, only one layer will be communicating with DbConnector. If you want to get rid of DbConnector (i.e. the actual persistence implementation), then you need to modify only a single layer to use a different persistence implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement all interfaces from javax.persistence - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html.

Comment: Do I have to implement annotation?